# LazyVeritcalGrid with multiple items in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've `LazyVerticalGrid` with 2 items as bloew

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    item { header() }
    items { content() }
}
```

`Content` is paging data and I'm showing empty view when no data is available. However, the issue is, if i use following code, `fillMaxSize()` will take max size of entire grid and centering the empty view will overlap the header.

```
EmptyView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(8.dp)
)
```

How do make sure that `fillMaxSize()` (or whatever) only center around `content()` ui and not the whole screen, that is, center below header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        item {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillParentSize()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                header()
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    } else {
        item { header() }
        items { content() }
    }
}
```

But it's strange that even though I can find fillParentMaxSize in the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxHeight(kotlin.Float)), I can't find it in my project. In that case, you can put EmptyView outside.

---

I get it. First, you can use `itemCount` to get the size of `LazyPagingItems`. Second, I think the `header` from the network can also be put outside the `LazyVerticalGrid`. Like this:

```kotlin
val headerData by viewModel.headerData.collectAsState()
val contentData by viewModel.contentData.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
Box {
    if (list.itemCount == 0) Column {
        header(headerData)
        EmptyView()
    } else LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        item { header(headerData) }
        items { content() }
    }
}
```

Also, if your project does not have a deep dependency on the Paging3 library, I recommend not using it. Here's what I did in my project: https://gist.github.com/FishHawk/6e4706646401bea20242bdfad5d86a9e

Comment: Issue with this is, I'm getting `LazyPagingItems` of data, not a `List` so can't check for `isEmpty`. Also, `header` and `content` both are fetched via separate network request. And yes, `fillParentMaxSize` is available for `LazyColumn` but not for `LazyVerticalGrid`